# draw graphs in tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{graphs}
\usetikzlibrary{graphs}

\begin{doument}
\begin{tikzpicture}[new set=import nodes]
\begin{scope}[nodes={set=import nodes}] % make all nodes part of this set
\node [red] (a) at (0,1) {$a$};
\node [red] (b) at (1,1) {$b$};
\node [red] (d) at (2,1) {$d$};
\end{scope}
\graph {
(import nodes);
% "import" the nodes
a -> b -> c -> d -> e;
};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

When I compiled this code, I got the error

```
! LaTeX Error: File `graphs.sty' not found.

Type X to quit or <RETURN> to proceed,
or enter new name. (Default extension: sty)

Enter file name:
```

Comment: Welcome! Do you have a package called **graphs** i.e. a file `graphs.sty`? Because I don't - it doesn't seem to be in TeX Live.

Answer (score 3):

LaTeX can only load existent packages. If you try to load a non-existent one, it will complain with an error.

No `graphs.sty` exists on my system. I think the package you probably want is TikZ:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{graphs}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[new set=import nodes]
\begin{scope}[nodes={set=import nodes}] % make all nodes part of this set
\node [red] (a) at (0,1) {$a$};
\node [red] (b) at (1,1) {$b$};
\node [red] (d) at (2,1) {$d$};
\end{scope}
\graph {
(import nodes);
% "import" the nodes
a -> b -> c -> d -> e;
};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: graph of nodes]